# ActionView::Template::Error at / uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm getting the following error when I try to load my app:

```
ActionView::Template::Error at /
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::EXPR_ARG
```

The error is found at `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` and the follow code is highlighted.

```
!!! 5
%html{:lang => "en"}
  %head
    = render partial: 'common/html_head'
  %body#static{ class: body_css_class }
    = content_for?(:base_content) ? yield(:base_content) : yield
```

Does anyone have an idea on what this is?

Comment: Are you by any chance upgrading your Rails version? What Haml version are you using?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that HAML code you posted, so it's probably a constant that's being used in the partial (common/html_head), base_content, or yield.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug in `haml` gem, version `5.0.1 - 5.0.4`.

You need to update the gem version to `5.0.4`.

[Source](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#504)